# pgr_createTopology not working is dynamic sql code

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I have the following dynamic sql query (left out many lines of code before this, but it works up to the pgr_createTopology element for creating the topology of an extracted stream network based on the query status below; however, no schema or tables are created in the database when it is completed.

The other variants:

```
-- working and seeing successful build, but no schema or tables created
SELECT pgr_createTopology('' || new_schema_name || '.rd_strms', 1.0, id := 'id', the_geom := 'geom', clean := 'true'); 

-- working, but not able to see pgr_topo status.
EXECUTE '
     SELECT pgr_createTopology(''' || new_schema_name || '''.rd_strms, 1.0, id := ''id'', the_geom := ''geom'', clean := true);
 ';
```

The query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_tables_in_schema(new_schema_name text)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        -- Setup routable stream network for Dijskstra algorithm
    EXECUTE '
    ALTER TABLE ' || new_schema_name || '.rd_strms ADD COLUMN source INT DEFAULT NULL';                             -- add required columns for pgr_dijkstra
    EXECUTE '
    ALTER TABLE ' || new_schema_name || '.rd_strms ADD COLUMN target INT DEFAULT NULL';
    EXECUTE '
    ALTER TABLE ' || new_schema_name || '.rd_strms ADD COLUMN cost DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT NULL';
    EXECUTE '
    ALTER TABLE ' || new_schema_name || '.rd_strms ADD COLUMN reverse_cost DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT NULL';
    
    EXECUTE '
    UPDATE ' || new_schema_name || '.rd_strms SET cost = ST_length(geom)';
    EXECUTE '
    UPDATE ' || new_schema_name || '.rd_strms SET reverse_cost = -1';

        SELECT pgr_createTopology('' || new_schema_name || '.rd_strms', 1.0, id := 'id', the_geom := 'geom', clean := 'true');
    
    END;
    $$;
```

the status output:

```
> NOTICE:  PROCESSING: NOTICE:  pgr_createTopology('schema.rd_strms', 1,
    > 'geom', 'id', 'source', 'target', rows_where := 'true', clean := t)
    > NOTICE:  Performing checks, please wait ..... NOTICE:  Creating
    > Topology, Please wait... NOTICE:  1000 edges processed NOTICE:  2000
    > edges processed NOTICE:  3000 edges processed NOTICE:  4000 edges
    > processed NOTICE:  5000 edges processed NOTICE:  6000 edges processed
    > NOTICE:  7000 edges processed NOTICE:  8000 edges processed NOTICE: 
    > 9000 edges processed NOTICE:  10000 edges processed NOTICE:  11000
    > edges processed NOTICE:  12000 edges processed NOTICE:  13000 edges
    > processed NOTICE:  14000 edges processed NOTICE:  15000 edges
    > processed NOTICE:  16000 edges processed NOTICE:  17000 edges
    > processed NOTICE:  18000 edges processed NOTICE:  19000 edges
    > processed NOTICE:  20000 edges processed NOTICE:  21000 edges
    > processed NOTICE:  -------------> TOPOLOGY CREATED FOR  21583 edges
    > NOTICE:  Rows with NULL geometry or NULL id: 0 NOTICE:  Vertices table
    > for table schema.rd_strms is: schema.rd_strms_vertices_pgr NOTICE: 
    > ----------------------------------------------
    > 
    > 
    > Query returned successfully in 3 min 41 secs.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this issue the use of the PERFORM statement instead of SELECT when executing the pgr_createTopology function call, as it does not expect any result data to be returned.

```
PERFORM pgr_createTopology('' || new_schema_name || '.rd_strms', 1.0, id := 'id', the_geom := 'geom', clean := 'true');
```